# Comparing List<Integer> by index

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist, compare

```
    List<Integer> listOne= new ArrayList<>();
    listOne.add(10);
    listOne.add(2);
    listOne.add(3);

    //Second Array

    List<Integer> listTwo= new ArrayList<>();
    listTwo.add(3);
    listTwo.add(7);
    listTwo.add(1);
```

I want to compare two List and give point to `listOne`or `listTwo` depending on which value is greater

```
[10, 2, 3] compare to [3, 7, 1]
if listOne.get(0) > listTwo.get(0) //add one point to listOne

if listOne.get(0) < listTwo.get(0) //add one point to listTwo
```

Here is my tested code

```
    static List<Integer> compareList(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
        ArrayList<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();
        output.add(0, 0);
        output.add(1, 0);
        int out = output.get(0);
        int out2 = output.get(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            if (a.get(i) > b.get(i)) {
                out = out + 1;
            } 
            if (a.get(i) < b.get(i)) {
                out2 = out2 + 1;
            } 
        }

        output.add(0, out);
        output.add(1, out2);
        return output;

    }
```

It works, but its not outputting the expected answer

> expected output : 2 1
>   output am getting : 2 1 0 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding two `0`s to the `List`, and then you are adding two more numbers at the start of the `List`, in addition to the `0`s.

Either remove these statements:

```
output.add(0, 0);
output.add(1, 0);
```

and keep these statements unchanged:

```
output.add(0, out);
output.add(1, out2);
```

Or just change these statements:

```
output.add(0, out);
output.add(1, out2);
```

to:

```
output.set(0, out);
output.set(1, out2);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
output.add(0, out);
output.add(1, out2);
```

You add items to indices 0 and 1, which push the previously entered zeroes to indices 2 and 3. `output` is now `[2, 1, 0, 0]`.

Remove

```
output.add(0, 0);
output.add(1, 0);
```

And change `out` and `out2` initialization to

```
int out = 0;
int out2 = 0;
```

Now you don't need to add the results by index either

```
output.add(out);
output.add(out2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove:

```
output.add(0, 0);
output.add(1, 0);
```

Works:

```
static List<Integer> compareList(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    ArrayList<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();
    int out = 0;
    int out2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if (a.get(i) > b.get(i)) {
            out = out + 1;
        }
        if (a.get(i) < b.get(i)) {
            out2 = out2 + 1;
        }
    }

    output.add(0, out);
    output.add(1, out2);
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayList documentation say:

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.
>   Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any
>   subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

So with statement `output.add(0, out)` and `output.add(1, out2)` you simply add items at 0 and 1 position in the list, pushing down what is already in the list (i.e. the values 0 and 0 are moved to the third and forth position).

An alternative approach would be to use HashMap as follows:

```
static List<Integer> compareList(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> output = new HashMap<>();
    output.put(0, 0);
    output.put(1, 0);
    int out = output.get(0);
    int out2 = output.get(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if (a.get(i) > b.get(i)) {
            out = out + 1;
        }
        if (a.get(i) < b.get(i)) {
            out2 = out2 + 1;
        }
    }

    output.put(0, out);
    output.put(1, out2);
    return new ArrayList(output.values());

}
```